# How to access saved object inside of conditional statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to access a newly created object inside of the conditional statement that created it:

```
if saved_object = Branch.new(params[:object]).save
  puts saved_object.id
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Naren Sisodya said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371162/171183), or you can use parentheses to disambiguate what is stored into `saved_object` (because right now `saved_object` holds the result of the `.save` call).

```
if (saved_object = Branch.new(params[:object])).save
  puts saved_object.id
end
```

In this form, the `saved_object` variable will hold the database record and then `.save` will be called on that record. This is likely what you intended, but not what you got due to operator precedence rules in ruby.

Answer (score 5):

Activerecord instance save method always return true/false, so you need to initialize the object and check .save on it like below

```
saved_object = Branch.new(params[:object])
if saved_object.save
  puts saved_object.id
end
```